# GitHub Sencha Touch project clones blank

Tags: github, sencha-touch-2, cloning

Recently I been learning Sencha Touch and cloning example projects such as [this](https://github.com/senchalearn/Tabs-and-Toolbars) one from GitHub.

However, when I have followed the steps at the bottom of that page to completion my cloned project just shows a blank white screen.

I've tried this some months back and it worked. The link above is to the second project in as many weeks that I have tried cloning.

I have been cloning onto a Linux Ubuntu LAMP server. My locally developed Sencha Touch projects work so it's not that my server discriminates against Sencha.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a look at the console, you'll see, that the Sencha Touch source file is missing.

You have to manually download Sencha Touch and copy `sencha-touch-debug.js` in the `Tabs-and-Toolbars/touch` folder.

You also have to copy all content of the Sencha Touch src folder (including files like `AbstractComponent.js`) in the `Tabs-and-Toolbars/touch/src` folder.

I think this is described in
https://github.com/senchalearn/Tabs-and-Toolbars/tree/master/touch too.

After adding the file and the content of the src, it was able to see the page.